# os.walk to find path to file issue (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, os.walk

I've just starting using python 2.7 and was using the following code to ascertain the path to a file:

```
import os, fnmatch

#find the location of sunnyexplorer.exe
def find_files(directory, pattern):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        for basename in files:
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(basename, pattern):
                filename = os.path.join(root, basename)
                yield filename

for filename in find_files('c:\users','*.sx2'): 
    print ('Found Sunny Explorer data in:', filename)
```

everthing seemed to be working fine until I tried to use the path and noticed an error. The program reports the path as:

```
c:\users\woody\Documents\SMA\Sunny Explorer
```

whereas the correct path is:

```
c:\users\woody\My Documents\SMA\Sunny Explorer
```

Comment: There is nothing in the code here that'd produce an incorrect path. `os.walk()` uses `os.listdir()`, nothing else, so your OS reported that there is a `Documents` folder there. Are you certain there is *no* `Documents` folder in the `woody` folder?

Comment: `My Documents` is called `Documents` in Windows Vista and 7, it's only the explorer showing you a different name.

Answer (score 2):

All versions of MS Windows since Vista store a user's documents in `C:\Users\%username%\Documents` by default.

However, they also include an [NTFS junction point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point) `C:\Users\%username%\My Documents` which points to the same location for backward compatibility.

The problem is, as I understand it, that you can't work with junction points with standard POSIX calls, so Python will not be able to use them without some Windows-specific extension module.

See also [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/194500/how-to-link-my-documents-folder-to-the-logical-documents-folder-in-windows-7) on superuser.com.

Comment: Many thanks for all the help. Windows explorer does show the folder as being called "My Documents" but I guess it must be due to the backwards compatibility issue. Now I know whats happening I can fix it. Thanks once again ;-) Woody